# Typescript catchAll getter or implementing array-like accessor

Tags: arrays, typescript

**Update: Solution**

I've adapted the accepted solution below slightly to fit my use-case. All Credits to the poster of the accepted solution.

```js
export class MyClass {
  //Declare we'll be using arbitrary number accessors
  [int: number]: any;

  list: any[] = [
    { name: 'apples', amount: 3, price: 10 },
    { name: 'bananas', amount: 1, price: 3 },
    { name: 'mangos', amount: 5, price: 18 },
  ];

  constructor() {
    //On instantiation, create the getters.
    this.createProperties()
  }

  private createProperties() {
    this.list.map((c, i) => {
      Object.defineProperty(this, i, {
        configurable: true,
        get: () => { 
          const v = this.getItemWithPrice(i);
          //Cleverly replace this getter with the value of the calculation. 
          //Keeps us from redoing the calculations when the same property is gotten again.
          Object.defineProperty(this.list, i, { value: v });
          return v
        },
      });
    });
  }

  getItemWithPrice(index: number) {
    //Some calculation before returning the item.
    if (!this.list[index].total) this.list[index].total = this.list[index].amount * this.list[index].price;

    return this.list[index];
  }
}

const someList = new MyClass();
//I can now access the list like so:
someList[1]; // { name: 'bananas', amount: 1, price: 3, total: 3 },
```

**Original Post**

I am trying to access items in a list, whose values will be calculated once requested. Consider the example:

```js
export class MyClass {
  list = [
    { name: 'apples', amount: 3, price: 10 },
    { name: 'bananas', amount: 1, price: 3 },
    { name: 'mangos', amount: 5, price: 18 },
  ];

  getItemWithPrice(index: number) {
    //Some calculation before returning the item.
    if (!this.list[index].total) this.list[index].total = this.list[index].amount * this.list[index].price;

    return this.list[index];
  }
}

const someList = new MyClass();
```

I would like to access this as an array like: `someList[1];`, which would return the value of `someList.getItemWithPrice(1);`.

In my use case the calculation is complex and there can be thousands of items, so I don't want to waste resources on making calculations that we don't need. (Otherwise I could've just calculated the prices up front and return an array with the results.)

I've been looking for ways to either extend Array or implement Iterator or even use Proxy, but I can't seem to make it work. I can make Proxy work, but it seems a bit hacky and I lose the constructor name of my original class. (Proxy is probably a decent fallback, but it seems it should be easier, knowing other languages that have magic methods, or IEnumerable interfaces, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While proxies can work, they're slow, weird, and can't be polyfilled for obsolete browsers. If I were you, I'd make an object with getters instead, by iterating over the numeric indicies of the original array.

```js
const listData = [
  { name: 'apples', amount: 3, price: 10 },
  { name: 'bananas', amount: 1, price: 3 },
  { name: 'mangos', amount: 5, price: 18 },
];

const someList = Object.defineProperties({}, Object.fromEntries(
  listData.map((item, i) => [i, {
    configurable: true,
    get() {
      console.log('Performing calculations');
      // Some calculation before returning the item.
      item.total = item.amount * item.price;
      // Set the property directly on the someList object, removing this getter
      Object.defineProperty(someList, i, { value: item });
      return item;
    }
  }])
));

console.log(someList[1]);
console.log(someList[2]);
console.log(someList[1]);
```

In TS, you'll need to declare the objects as possibly having a `total` property.

```
const listData: Array<{ name: string, amount: number, price: number, total?: number }> = [
```

Comment: I did not know I could dynamically define getter functions like that! I had come across `Object.defineProperties` in my search, but couldn't find a way to get that to work. Thank you for showing me this!